# View docs from Git hub repository

Tags: makefile, python-sphinx

I have cloned the repository - https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain. There is a docs folder in this repository that has a folder named 'source' and files named 'Makefile' and 'supply-chain-build-docs'

I want to know if I build the contents in this directory, whether I would be able to view additional documentation other than what is in ReadMe.md file.

If so, how should I build and view the files? I have installed sphinx.

In which port will I be able to see the html documentation after the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the `supply-chain-build-docs` file you will notice the instructions to build the docs is mentioned inside.

Description:
  Builds the environment needed to build the Sawtooth Supply Chain docs
  Running the image will put the docs in
  sawtooth-supply-chain/docs/build on your local machine.

Build:

```
  $ cd sawtooth-supply-chain
  $ docker build . -f docs/supply-chain-build-docs -t supply-chain-build-docs
```

Run:

```
  $ cd sawtooth-supply-chain
  $ docker run -v $(pwd):/project/sawtooth-supply-chain supply-chain-build-docs
```

This documentation although assumes that you already have docker installed. The guide to install it in ubuntu can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04)

> In which port will I be able to see the html documentation after the build?

Once you run both the steps above you can find a neat pdf on the location `sawtooth-supply-chain/docs/build/latex` named as `sawtooth.pdf` ready for you :)

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked like a charm